# mysqli prepared statement not working in login

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to login a user, but it returns 0 in num rows. what is the problem?

config.php

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$titulo="config";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$bd="st";

$mysqli_link = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>
```

no error is showing.

login.php

```
include("config.php");
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT id, user FROM cadastro WHERE binary user = ? AND binary senha = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); //it works!!**

$num = $stmt->num_rows;
echo $num; //$num always 0 why?

if($num > 0)
{...
```

I type user and pass correctly, im converting mysql to mysqli.

**EDIT-------------------------------------------------------**

with $stmt->store_result(); it works!
but now i have an error in this part:

```
        $i=$mysqli_link->prepare("UPDATE cadastro SET `lastsession` = ? WHERE `user` = ? LIMIT 1;");
        $i=$mysqli_link->bind_param('ss', $sessionid, $user);
        $i=$mysqli_link->execute();
```

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 45**

Comment: Try to call: `$stmt->store_result();` right after your execute call, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: `WHERE binary user = `... I had never seen that before. Is this correct?

Comment: it show 1! 1 and
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param()

Comment: ^ @GabrielaDias So did my comment worked for you? But you also got an error? if yes please update your question with the progress and also post the **exact** error message which you get

Comment: @Sean My bad... about `binary` lol too much coffee. That's what you get for doing too many things at the same time.

Comment: @bcesars see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html `The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character.`

Comment: @Fred-ii- no harm, no foul. I have never seen it used before either, so I had to RTM.

Comment: @Sean I think I'll go and have me a few gallons of water to thin out the caffeine lol thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you have been on a roll on SO today, so hopefully the diluted caffeine doesn't negatively impact your future performance.

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` by `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli_link->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` see what  that says besides the present error.

Comment: @Sean A bit too much more "rock" than "roll" lol but I'll get that heavy thing out of the way soon enough. ;-)

Comment: Why did you prepend all your new code with `$i=`?

Comment: $stmt->store_result(); works! why I need this? but now i have a problem in a update query as I edit above!

Comment: @Sean should i use $stmt in my new code too?

Comment: mysqli OO is new for me, sorry my ignorance!

Comment: you can use `$i`, `$stmt`, or anything else, but only on the first line. You then reuse that in `$i->`, `$stmt->`, etc. Right now you are overwriting the object with each `$i=`

Comment: thank you friends! it works now! just one more question, what is this $stmt->store_result(); ?? why i need this to work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have shown us the real code! And the problem is that you have to use the `$stmt` variable like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("UPDATE cadastro SET `lastsession` = ? WHERE `user` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $sessionid, $user);
//^^^ See here
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 46